# more than one keywords metatag on the website

Tags: html, seo

Is it correct approach to have more than one keywords metatag on the website ?

for example:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="test1" />
<meta name="keywords" content="test2" />
```

or is it an error ?

Thank You very much for help

Answer (score 4):

As taken from [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/18629/14414)

The `keywords` meta tag doesn't do anything anymore, at least as far as most search engines are concerned. You're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. Search engines index by content nowadays, and they do that without your help.

See [the Wikipedia article on the meta tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_tag#The_keywords_attribute):

> Search engines began dropping support for metadata provided by the meta element in 1998, and by the early 2000s, most search engines had veered completely away from reliance on meta elements. In July 2002, AltaVista, one of the last major search engines to still offer support, finally stopped considering them.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error; any number of `meta` tags may be used. But as @Nerd-Herd points out, keyword meta tags are hardly useful at all.

If you use such tags, there is usually no reason to use more than one of them per page, as it is simpler to write just `<meta name="keywords" content="test1, test2">`.

In theory, if you use keywords of different languages, then you have a reason to use more than one tag, because the language identification is per element, e.g.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="liberty" lang="en">   
<meta name="keywords" content="liberté" lang="fr">
```

But this is just theoretical, since search engines probably ignore keyword `meta` tags, and almost surely ignore `lang` attributes in general.

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags "description" and "keywords" are very important. They should be distinct for each page of website.

We read in "Google Search Engine Optimization Starter Guide"

> Description meta tags are important because Google **might** use
>   them as snippets for your pages. Note that we say "might" because
>   Google may choose to use a relevant section of your page's visible
>   text if it does a good job of matching up with a user's query.
>
> Adding description meta tags to each of your pages is always a good practice in case Google
>   cannot find a good selection of text to use in the snippet. -Page 6

Emphasise of theirs.